# Passing std::real to ranges::sort as a projection doesn't compile

Tags: c++, c++20, projection, complex-numbers, std-ranges

I am trying to sort a vector of complex numbers by their real components by passing std::real as the projection argument, which doesn't compile. I can't seem figure out why, mostly because the compile errors are very verbose.

Using a lambda works, but is ugly and I'd much rather not do it that way. A similar problem, sorting a vector of vectors by size, compiles and works perfectly. Here is what I've tried:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef complex<double> cp;

int main() {
  vector<cp> P = {{2, 3}, {12, 30}, {40, 50}, {5, 1}, {12, 10}, {3, 4.2}};
  ranges::sort(P, {}, real<double>); // doesn't compile
  ranges::sort(P, {}, real<cp>); // doesn't compile
  ranges::sort(P, {}, &cp::real); // doesn't compile
  auto pj = [](cp a) {return real(a);};
  ranges::sort(P, {}, pj); // compiles and works, but is ugly

  vector<vector<int>> tst = {{1, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {1}};
  ranges::sort(tst, {}, size<vector<int>>); // compiles and works
  ranges::sort(tst, {}, &vector<int>::size); // compiles and works
  auto tstpj = [](vector<int>& a) {return size(a);};
  ranges::sort(tst, {}, tstpj); // compiles and works, but is ugly
}
```

Why doesn't the version with complex numbers work, and how can I fix it?

Comment: In practice, `std::real<T>` has several overloads, so `&std::real<T>` is ambiguous.

Comment: and pedantically `std::real` is not an [addressable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction).

Comment: How ugly is "ugly"? You don't have to create the lambda separately, but can do `ranges::sort(P, {}, [](cp a) { return real(a); });`

Answer (score 0):

> A similar problem, sorting a vector of vectors by size, compiles and
> works perfectly.

However, [this is unspecified behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#6), you are not allowed to directly take the address of the standard library function unless the standard specifies that it is an *addressable function*.

In C++20, a more simple way is to take [*customization point object*](https://eel.is/c++draft/customization.point.object) `ranges::size` as the projection:

```
ranges::sort(tst, {}, ranges::size);
```

For `std::complex` cases, using lambda is the most appropriate choice. But you can simplify the code with macros, for example:

```
#define MEMBER_FUN(memer_fun) \
[](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x).memer_fun(); }
```

This makes it easier to construct lambdas that invokes the object's member function

```
vector<complex<double>> P = /* */;
ranges::sort(P, {}, MEMBER_FUN(real));

vector<vector<int>> tst = /* */;
ranges::sort(tst, {}, MEMBER_FUN(size));
```